# issues in text view in android Application

Tags: android, textview

Hi, I have small issues in text view, can anybody help me?

```
<TextView android:layout_marginLeft="10dip" android:id="@+id/TextView05" android:text="Latitude: " android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:textSize="20dip" android:layout_marginRight="5dip" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
```

**problem**

1. I want to hide the text view dynamically, but I need to asign the value in textview and I want to get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, just like `jitendra sharma's` method.

```
TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextView05);
String text = tv.getText().toString();
```

and after, set visibility here

```
tv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

Just set Visibility to Invisible or VISIBILITY GONE in XML or Activity, still you would able to get Reference of view in activity class:

```
TextView txt=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView05);
```

And you can fetch its text using:

```
String text=txt.getText().toString();
```